# In-memory H2 database, insert scripts not persisting

Tags: database, insert, h2, persist

I'm tying to use H2 as an in-memory database for my unit testing.  I'm wiring everything together through Spring.  Everything *seems* to work fine.  The DB loads up, the ddl sql file runs, as does the dml sql (or so it seems).

I can run a test that creates a record in the database, then retrieves and validates it was appropriately persisted.  So this tells me the ddl scripts ran fine.

The issue is when I try to receive a record that was inserted via the dml script, i get nothing.

I tried putting the same insert statement in the file twice and do indeed receive a unique constraint error, which tells me they are running...but for some reason not *persisting*.

DDL:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `schema`.`region` ;CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `schema`.`region` (
  `region_id` INT(11) NOT NULL ,
  `name` VARCHAR(56) NOT NULL ,
  `description` VARCHAR(512) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`region_id`) );
```

DML:

```
INSERT INTO `schema`.`region` (`region_id`, `name`, `description`) VALUES (1001, 'TEST', 'TESTING');
```

URL:

```
jdbc:h2:file:db_test;MODE=MYSQL;INIT=create schema if not exists test_db\\;runscript from 'classpath:test_ddl.sql'\\;runscript from 'classpath:test_dml.sql'
```

Any help would be helpful.

thanks

Comment: I have exactly the same problem, have you fixed it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Where are the Database Files Stored?](http://h2database.com/html/faq.html#database_files) in the FAQ. With the database URL you used, `jdbc:h2:file:db_test`, the files are stored in the *current working directory*. Depending on where you start your application, this is a different place, so a different database is used.

I suggest to use `jdbc:h2:~/db/test_db...` instead.

> I'm tying to use H2 as an in-memory database

You are actually using a persistent database, see the [database URL overview](http://h2database.com/html/features.html#database_url).

Comment: Yes, you are correct about my url indicating a file not in-memory db. My intent is to ultimately use in-memory (jdbc:h2:mem:...) I was playing with other options to see if it would work and inaccurately posted on here.  my apologies.

with that said, I did use the ~/db/... format and this is giving more information, which is what i need.  

The bulk of my trace file contains "org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Column "FOREIGN" not found; SQL statement:" errors

I have a basic statements as follows:

Comment: The bulk of my trace file contains "org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Column "FOREIGN" not found; SQL statement:" errors

ex statement:
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `s1`.`tableA` (
`id` INT(11) NOT NULL ,
`name` VARCHAR(56) NOT NULL ,
`description` VARCHAR(512) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`) );

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `s1`.`tableB` (
`tableB_id` INT(11) NOT NULL ,
`name` VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL ,
`tableA_id` INT(11) NOT NULL ,
 PRIMARY KEY (`tableB_id`) ,
 CONSTRAINT `fk_tableA`  FOREIGN KEY (`tableA_id` )  REFERENCES `s1`.`tableA` (`id` )  ON DELETE NO ACTION  ON UPDATE NO ACTION);

Comment: This sounds like a different problem now. Could you post the complete error message (including error code) and all stack traces?

Comment: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Column "FOREIGN" not found; SQL statement:
alter table s1.customer_network drop foreign key FKF3FBC2CDB2644654 [42122-168]
 at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:329)
 at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:169)
 at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:146)
 at org.h2.table.Table.getColumn(Table.java:605)
 at org.h2.command.Parser.parseAlterTable(Parser.java:4874)
 at org.h2.command.Parser.parseAlter(Parser.java:4315)
 at org.h2.command.Parser.parsePrepared(Parser.java:306)

Comment: at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:279)
 at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:251)
 at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:217)
 at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareLocal(Session.java:415)
 at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareCommand(Session.java:364)
 at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1109)

Comment: at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.executeUpdateInternal(JdbcStatement.java:121)
 at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.executeUpdate(JdbcStatement.java:110)
 at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.execute(SchemaExport.java:421)
 at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.drop(SchemaExport.java:396)
 at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.execute(SchemaExport.java:269)
 at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.drop(SchemaExport.java:229)
 at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.close(SessionFactoryImpl.java:959)

Comment: it's happening as it's loading the hbm files.

Comment: This is now about Hibernate so I guess it's a different question.

Comment: When I run this against the mysql database, all runs well.  Also, the exception is thrown on a create statement, so this would lead me to believe H2 is not understanding some configuration or association somewhere, no?

Comment: Please create a new question. In your original one you didn't say anything about Hibernate, and the exception is different.